# Facebook Connect subdomains with unique connect and callback URLs

Tags: facebook, subdomain

Like most good developers I have a separate testing environment for my web app. For example, I have `www.test.example.com` which is the testing site and the production site is `www.example.com`.

I have set my Base Domain to example.com but how do I set the connect URL so that it goes to my test site when I login from the test site? Do I need to create a separate app for each subdomain? Is it possible to set the URLs dynamically using [Admin.setAppProperties](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Admin.setAppProperties)?

List of [Application Properties](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/ApplicationProperties)

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a number of facebook applications (you can go to my website through my profile) but what i do is create a folder in my site not create a sub-domain like you said. Then i create settings for my folder on facebook application settings. This is the faster and easier way to do it.

For example I create a folder like `www.example.com/fbtest_app/`. Once everything is fine, i move all stuff and update the settings for the final folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that won't work in my situation with FB Connect. Each environment (development,test,production) needs to be as close to production as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're doing the authorization flow, you can pass a `next` URL for the old auth flows, or `redirect_uri` for the [OAuth2 flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) which will allow you to specify an arbitrary URL under the base domain you've set.